# Linking OpenCL Causes Segfault

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, opencl, nvidia

While trying to get a simple opencl program running, I encountered segfaults when linking opencl. I have managed to reduce the source to this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    const std::string str = "this causes a segfault\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with this command:

```
g++ -g -std=c++14 -I/opt/cuda/include reduced.c++ -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -o reduced -lOpenCL
```

Using this compiler:

```
g++ (Funtoo 4.9.3-r3) 4.9.3
```

On funtoo. Here is the backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff793acf1 in std::locale::_S_initialize() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff793ad33 in std::locale::locale() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7937b44 in std::ios_base::Init::Init() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00000000004009e9 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4.9.3/iostream:74
#5  0x0000000000400a12 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_main () at reduced.c++:6
#6  0x0000000000400a65 in __libc_csu_init ()
#7  0x00007ffff703df3f in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x0000000000400889 in _start ()
```

Compiling with `g++ -g -std=c++14 reduced.c++ -o reduce` causes the program to stop segfaulting. My graphics card is an nvidia 560 Ti and I'm running the version `364.19` of the proprietary nvidia drivers on a 4.5.2 kernel from gentoo-sources.

I initially thought this was an abi problem but as far as I can tell, the `std::string` abi changed at `5.0.0`. Compiling with clang prevents the segfaulting in this reduced example, but not in my original program.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I have tried regenerating locales like so:

```
elliot@funbox ~> sudo locale-gen
 * Generating locale-archive: forcing # of jobs to 1
 * Generating 2 locales (this might take a while) with 1 jobs
 *  (1/2) Generating en_GB.UTF-8 ...                                                                                                 [ ok ]
 *  (2/2) Generating en_US.UTF-8 ...                                                                                                 [ ok ]
 * Generation complete
elliot@funbox ~
```

It does not stop the segfault from happening.

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem, the only difference being that when I comment out my function that does some regex stuff it works doesn't complain. Did you end up finding a fix? I'm desperate!

Comment: No progress on a fix yet unfortunately.

Comment: Darn it! I ended up rewriting my code not to use std::regex, and then after shuffling the includes a few times it stopped producing errors. I think in the end it happened because I was including opencl before iostream, but I will never know this for sure.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the standard library implementation. Compiling with clang using libc++ causes the error to occur elsewhere. I still can't get it to run though

Comment: I've got similar bug in minGW 5.3.0 and 6.1.0. It segfaults on /include/c++/bits/locale_facets.h:877 which is `return this->do_widen(__c);` in `char_type widen(char __c) const` function. Adding `-g` fixes the issue. I haven't reduced it it, but the issues are pretty similar. Have you reported the bug?

Comment: I haven't reported it yet. I'm not sure who to report it to. Nvidia as a driver bug?

Comment: @Ell actually I'm not linking with OpenCL, there probably bug somewhere else and my code is causing it just like OpenCL's